# Breakpoint at the end of the method hits twice

Tags: c#, itext, breakpoints

I am using IText to generate some basic PDF.

Here the code:

```
 public void GeneratePdf()
    {
        using var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter("hello.pdf")
        {
            using var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter)
            {
                using var document = new Document(pdfDocument)
                {
                    document.Add(new Paragraph(_cotizacionVm.InfoSyca.Nombre));
                    document.Add(new Paragraph(_cotizacionVm.InfoSyca.Nombre));
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("HI");
    }// The breakpoint here is hit twice
```

Something strange is happening (at least for me).

The last curly brace of the method is hit twice, no other "HI" is printed.

Can anyone give me an idea of what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My wild guess is that the debugger is giving you a chance to pause execution between `Dispose` calls (due to the end of the `using` blocks).

Comment: By the way, each of your using statements end with a `;`, meaning that they are the [C# 8 using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations) feature, and not the traditional `using (something) { code }` blocks.  With that in mind, the scopes (denoted by `{` and `}` are unnecessary).

Comment: @Llama I know, I was just testing this behavior and forgot to delete them, thanks anyway!

Comment: @Victor If you remove them, does that change the result re breakpoints. If it does, John might be onto something.

Comment: @Llama already tried it, same behavior.